# Identification of zinc/aluminium/magnesium with copper sulphate solution

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment, experimental-chemistry

We are doing an experiment and would like to be able to identify zinc/aluminium/ magnesium . Would a copper sulphate solution work ? I hear that it turns black on contact with zinc, stays clear on contact with aluminium and fizzes on contact with magnesium.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/11021/identification-of-zinc-aluminium-magnesium-with-copper-sulphate-solution/11026?s=8|0.0466#11026

Answer (score 2):

If you mean identification of the metals in their elemental form, then yes, it might be possible to distinguish between them with an aqueous $\ce{CuSO4}$ solution due to the different reactions.

Zinc in $\ce{CuSO4}$ will be oxidized to colorless $\ce{Zn^2+}$, while $\ce{Cu^2+}$ is reduced to elemental copper, because copper is the more noble metal. The $\ce{Cu}$ precipitate is normally not black, although it can appear dark in the background of the blue solution. It can also form a layer on the piece of zinc, and in the course of the reaction, the initially blue solution will become more and more colorless.

$$\ce{Zn + CuSO4 \rightarrow Cu\downarrow + ZnSO4}$$

Aluminium does not react at all because it is protected by its native oxide layer which is stable in this solution. Magnesium, however, is oxidized under evolution of $\ce{H2}$ gas, which fizzes off from the solution because it is poorly soluble in water. The reaction will gradually become slower when insoluble $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$ passivates the metal surface.

$$\ce{Mg + 2 H2O \rightarrow Mg(OH)2 + H2\uparrow}$$